# Web api post - passed string value is null at server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-post, visual-studio-2015

My project is brand new Asp.net 2015 MVC6 beta 8 web application.

I get value as null when I call Web api with post type from C# code.

My server side code:

```
// POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            if( null != value )
                do something;
        }
```

My clientside is:

```
StringContent cstrJson = new StringContent("{ mesage: hello}"
                                            , System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var result = await client1.PostAsync("http://localhost:68888/api/myApi/", cstrJson);
```

I tried all different combinations of encoding and media, but no improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's null because the body couldn't be parsed as a string. The content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of text/plain.

You may want to rethink using a string anyway if your client is sending json, you should accept application/json on the server and let the framework parse it for you.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(MyObject value)
{
    var msg = value.Message;
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Client Side:

```
var cstrJson = new StringContent("{'Message' : 'hello'}", System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, "application/json");

var result = await client1.PostAsync("http://localhost:68888/api/myApi/", cstrJson);
```